# Postgresql syntex error for function declaration with default argument

Tags: postgresql

Sorry, noob question. Therefore I will keep it short. Code, error message and specific part of code line are below.

Many thanks.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS pfi_pilot.fr_GetCrossTrades(IN par_from_dt TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, IN par_to_dt TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, IN par_asset_classes VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'ALL', IN par_debug CHAR(255) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL, IN return_code int DEFAULT NULL, IN p_refcur refcursor DEFAULT NULL, IN p_refcur_2 refcursor DEFAULT NULL, IN p_refcur_3 refcursor DEFAULT NULL, IN p_refcur_4 refcursor DEFAULT NULL, IN p_refcur_5 refcursor DEFAULT NULL);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pfi_pilot.fr_GetCrossTrades(IN par_from_dt TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, IN par_to_dt TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, IN par_asset_classes VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'ALL', IN par_debug CHAR(255) DEFAULT 'N' is NOT NULL, IN return_code int DEFAULT NULL, IN p_refcur refcursor DEFAULT NULL, IN p_refcur_2 refcursor DEFAULT NULL, in p_refcur_3 refcursor DEFAULT NULL, in p_refcur_4 refcursor DEFAULT NULL, in p_refcur_5 refcursor DEFAULT NULL)
```

Error message:
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"
Position: 173

at:

```
IN par_asset_classes VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'ALL'
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the parameters for the DROP FUNCTION if you have not overloaded your function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS pfi_pilot.fr_GetCrossTrades;
```

If you did overload the function, you should only list the data types (without the parameter name, mode or default value):

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS pfi_pilot.fr_GetCrossTrades(
        TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, 
        TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, 
        VARCHAR(255), 
        CHAR(255), 
        int, 
        refcursor, refcursor, refcursor, refcursor, refcursor);
```

---

Note that use of the `char` data type is [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29).

There is also no real need to use `varchar(n)` for a parameter, using `text` for both parameters would make your life a lot easier.